# opencv:black border using a mask

Tags: python, opencv

when i merge two images using a mask, a get a black border. Any solutions for this?

```
enlarged_base_img = np.zeros((height,width, 3), np.uint8)
next_img_warp=cv2.warpPerspective(images[teller], transformation, (width, height))
(ret,data_map) = cv2.threshold(cv2.cvtColor(next_img_warp, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY), 
    0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
enlarged_base_img = cv2.add(enlarged_base_img,eind, 
mask=np.bitwise_not(data_map), 
dtype=cv2.CV_8U)
cv2.imwrite("mask.png",data_map)


final_img = cv2.add(enlarged_base_img, eind,dtype=cv2.CV_8U)
cv2.imshow("uitk",enlarged_base_img)
cv2.imwrite("final.png",final_img)
cv2.imwrite("imagemask.png",enlarged_base_img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image: black_border]

Comment: What are the sizes of the two images and the mask? If all not the same, then that is where the issue resides.

Comment: @SaraDeh please add the images used as an input to form the [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).